# Equivalent HTML code for Escape characters accepts in TextBlock

Tags: c#, html, xml, wpf, xaml

Need some HTML code for Escape characters that accepts and do its functionality in a `TextBlock`.

**For Example:** `&#10;` for `\n`

My requirement is, I have a `XML` file which holds a field named `Memo` and it need to hold some text like in the below image

[image]

For CCJS, i need a tab to make it center. like wise the rest of text to be aligned.

**XML tag:**

```
memo="\tCCJS&#10;\t==========&#10;&#10; If the &quot;CCJS&quot; field is customized on the General Occurrence screen, then the same custamization should be made to the &quot;CCJS Status&quot; field on the conclusion block."
```

**Above given is just for an example, I have more text like these** so i need some set of HTML code to have all these Text accepted in `xml` and `Textblock`

I have gone through [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_ascii.asp).. Still i dont found code for `Tab`. if i would get a full list of these codes, it would be helpful..

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use LineBreak and Run within TextBlock Element?

Comment: You do understand that a 'tab' is just a pre-determined number of spaces, don't you?

Comment: This Text is going to assign in a `Property` and that to be bound with  a TextBlock. So `LineBreak` cannot be used.

Comment: @Sheridan: Yes, Its a predefined spaces can be used for this, but still there is a option for `\t` will be fine. I can keep this as my last option.. Thanks..

Comment: Can you use <![CDATA[ ...]]> ?http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp

Comment: As far as I know, HTML don't have inhouse support for Tab.  Mostly WebDevs prefers to give padding for Tabbing!

Comment: You can use `&#x000A;` as a new line character in XAML, but I haven't come across a code for a tab mark.

Comment: I may be getting wrong end of stick but here goes. Guessing you are creating single-page web app. In which case, forget about the newlines and apply CSS to the element you are displaying the data in. I can enlarge in answer if you want more ...

Answer (score 0):

I've always just used the Line Feed character (which will work in xaml and is html encoded, it's also already included your example)

Dec. = `&#10;`
Hex. = `&#xa;`

As example;
`<TextBlock Text="Line One&#10;Line Two"/>`

Hope this helps.

PS - for your tabs, just get your spacing correct and utilize `Preserve Whitespace` / `xml:space="preserve"`

Comment: I have already tried `xml:space="preserve"`, but there is no difference after it was removed. My white spaces are shown without these tag.

Comment: @Sankarann So you've found an answer then?

Comment: Not yet.. But i moved to another way of implementation to achieve my requirement...